# Algorithm(s) / approach

Tags: algorithm

Recently I came across this question and I have no clue where or how to start solving it. Here is the question:

> There are 8 statues 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 . Each statue is pointing in one of the following four direction North, South, East or West. John would like to arrange the statues so that they all point in same direction. However John is restricted to the following 8 moves which correspond to rotation each statue listed 90 degrees clockwise. (N to E, E to S, S to W, W to N)
>
> Moves
>
> A: 0,1
>
> B: 0,1,2
>
> C: 1,4,5,6
>
> D: 2,5
>
> E: 3,5
>
> F: 3,7
>
> G: 5,7
>
> H: 6,7
>
> Help John figure out fewest number of moves to help point all statues in one direction.
>
> Input : A string initialpos consisting of 8 chars. Each char is either 'N,'S,'E,'W'
>
> Output: An integer which represents fewest no. of moves needed to arrange statues in same direction. If no sequence possible then return -1.
>
> Sample test cases:
>
> input: SSSSSSSS
>
> Output: 0
>
> Explanation: All statues point in same direction. So it takes 0 moves
>
> Test case 1:
>
> Input : WWNNNNNN
>
> Output: 1
>
> Exp: John can use Move A which will make all statues point to North
>
> Test Case 3:
>
> input: NNSEWSWN
>
> Output: 6
>
> Exp: John uses Move A twice, B once, F twice, G once. This will result in all statues facing W.

The only approach I was able to think of was to brute force it. But since the moves can be done multiple times (test case 3), what would be the limit to applying the moves before we conclude that such an arrangement is not possible (i.e output -1)? I am looking for specific types of algorithms that can be used to solve this, also what part of the problem is used in identifying an algorithm.

Comment: This is not a homework problem. Apparently it is a question in an Amazon interview: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5380513791475712

Answer (score 2):

Note that the *order* of moves makes no difference, only the *set* (with repetition). Also note that making the same move 4 times is equivalent to doing nothing, so there is never any reason to make the same move more than 3 times. This reduces the space to 4<sup>8</sup> possible sequences, which isn't too terrible, but we can still do better than brute force.

1. The only move that treats 0 and 1 differently is C, so apply C as many times as is necessary to bring 0 and 1 into alignment. We mustn't use C any more than that, and C is the only thing that can move 4, so the remaining task is to align everything to 4.

   The only way to move 6 is with H; apply H to align 6.

   Now to align 3 and 7. We could do it with E and G, but we may have the option to use F as a short-cut. The optimal number of F moves is not yet clear, so we'll use E and G, and come back to F later.

   Apply D to align 5.

   Apply B to align 2.

   Apply A to align 0 and 1.

   Now revisit F, and see whether the short-cut actually saves moves. Pick the optimal number of F moves. (This is easy even by brute force, since there are only 4 possibilities to test.)

Answer (score 2):

The directions N, E, W, S with operation of turning are congruent with `Z mod 4` with `succ`: turn N = `(succ 0) mod 4`, turn W twice = `(succ succ 2) mod 4` etc.

Each move is a vector of zeros (no change) and ones (turn by one) being added to inputs: say you have your example of NNSEWSWN, which would be `[0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 0]`, and you push the button A, which is `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, resulting in `[1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 0]`, or EESEWSWN.

Now if you do a bunch of different operations, they all add up. Thus, you can represent the whole system with this matrix equation:

```
(start + move_matrix * applied_moves) mod 4 = finish
```

where `start` and `finish` are position vectors as described above, `move_matrix` the 8x8 matrix with all the moves, and `applied_moves` a 8-element vector saying how many times we push each button (in range `0..3`).

From this, you can get:

```
applied_moves = (inverse(move_matrix) * (finish - start)) mod 4
```

Number of applied moves is then just this:

```
num_applied_moves = sum((inverse(move_matrix) * (finish - start)) mod 4)
```

Now just plug in the four different values for `finish` and see which one is least.

You can use matlab, numpy, octave, APL, whatever rocks your boat, as long as it supports matrix algebra, to get your answer very quickly and very easily.

Comment: Can you explain a few things to me? First how is vector-matrix addition defined in the equation `(start + move_matrix * applied_moves) mod 4 = finish`. start is a vector but move_matrix*applied_moves yields a matrix. So how do you add a vector and a matrix together? Also I don't get how you got from applied_moves to num_applied_moves. I don't see the relationship between the two.

Comment: `move_matrix*applied_moves` is a vector, not a matrix, because `applied_moves` is a vector. `num_applied_moves` is just the sum of `applied_moves` elements: three times A and two times B is five moves, right?

Comment: Nevermind I got it, sorry I failed to understand it earlier. :) Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: If you find `applied_moves`, is that guaranteed to be the shortest solution? or an integer one? Does `move_matrix` have an inverse?

Comment: @fgb: There are exactly four solutions, one for each possible direction of `finish`. Finding the smallest one should not be difficult. It is possible that `move_matrix` is not invertible; I believe that in such a case, one or more of the statues will probably be immobile, or several statues always move simultaneously, or several buttons do the exact same thing. If such statues face inconsistent directions there is no solution; if they can be solved, one would need to collapse the repeating rows/columns and treat the twinned statues/buttons as one. Presence of fixed statues = 1 solution, not 4.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a little like homework... but I would go with this line of logic.

Run a loop seeing how many moves it would take to move all the statues to face one direction.  You would get something like allEast = 30, allWest = 5, etc.  Take the lowest sum and corresponding direction would be the answer.  With that mindset its pretty easy to build an algorithm to handle computation.

Answer (score 0):

Brute-force could work. A move applied 4 times is the same as not applying the move at all, so each move can only be applied 0, 1, 2, or 3 times.

The order of the moves does not matter. Move a followed by b is the same as b followed by a.

So there are only 4^8 = 65536 possible combinations of moves.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution is to note that there are only 4^8 = 64k different configurations.  Each move can therefore be represented as a table of 64k 2 byte indices taking one configuration to the next. The 2 bytes e.g. are divided into 8 2-bit fields 0=N, 1=E, 2=S, 3=W. Further we can use one more table of bits to say which of the 64k configurations have all statues pointing in the same direction.

These tables don't need to be computed at run time.  They can be preprocessed while writing the program and stored.

Let table A[c] give the configuration resulting after applying move A to configuration c. and Z[c] return true iff c is a successful config.

So we can use a kind of BFS:

```
1. Let C be a set of configurations, initially C = { s } where s is the starting config
2. Let n = 0 
3. If Z[c] is true for any c in C, return n
4. Let C' be the result of applying A, B, ... H to each element of C.  
5. Set C = C', n = n + 1 and go to 3
```

C can theoretically grow to be almost 64k in size, but the bigger it gets, the better the chances of success, so this ought to be quite fast in practice.